# Parametrization of a helicoid

Tags: differential-geometry, parametrization

I am looking at the following exercise:

A helicoid is the surface swept out by an aeroplane propeller, when both the aeroplane and its propeller move at constant speed.

If the aeroplane is flying along the $z$-axis, show that the helicoid can be parametrized as $$\sigma (u, v)=(v \cos u, v \sin u, \lambda u)$$ where $\lambda$ is a constant.

$$$$

Could you give me some hints how we could show that?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

After that I have to show that the cotangent of the angle that the standard unit normal of $\sigma$ at a point $p$ makes with the $z$-axis is proportional to the distance of $p$ from the $z$-axis.

I have found that the standard unit normal of $\sigma$ is $$\textbf{N}=\frac{(-\lambda \sin u, \lambda \cos u, -v)}{\sqrt{\lambda^2+v^2}}$$

The unit vector of the $z$-axis is $Z=(0,0,1)$, right?

So we have $$Z\cdot \textbf{N}=|Z||\textbf{N}|\cos (Z,\textbf{N}) \Rightarrow \frac{-v}{\sqrt{\lambda^2+v^2}}=\cos (Z,\textbf{N})$$ and $$|Z\times \textbf{N}\|=|Z||\textbf{N}|\sin (Z,\textbf{N}) \Rightarrow \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda^2+v^2}}=\sin (Z,\textbf{N})$$ So $$\cot (Z,\textbf{N})=-\frac{v}{\lambda}$$

Which is the distance of $p$ from the $z$-axis?

Comment: do you want to first write the trajectory equation of helicoid and parametrize it to $\sigma(u,v)$ @mary star

Comment: How does the trajectory equation of helicoid look like? @Boris

Comment: please make the question more clear @mary star

Comment: Yes, and the (absolute value of the) sine of the angle is $|Z\times N|$. The distance of $p = \sigma(u,v)$ to the $z$-axis is the distance from $p$ to its projection onto the $z$-axis, which is $v$. Does that seem right?

Comment: Why is the distance from $p$ to its projection onto the $z$-axis equal to $v$ ? @FrancisBegbie

Comment: Its projection oton the $z$-axis is $(0,0,\lambda u)$, and $|\sigma(u,v)-(0,0,\lambda u)| = \dots$?

Comment: So as I have calculated in my initial post, we get $\cot (Z, \textbf{N})=-\frac{v}{\lambda}$ and the distance of $p$ from the $z$-axis is $v$, so the cotangent is a multiple of the distance, so they are proportional, right? @FrancisBegbie

Comment: Yep all right :)

Comment: Nice!! Thanks a lot!! :-) @FrancisBegbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a patch $\sigma(u,v)$ for $(u,v)\in (0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)$ to be the position at time $u$ of a point along the propellor blade that lies at distance $v$ from the propellor's center. If we project the patch onto the $xy$-plane (only look at the $x$ and $y$ coordinates), then we are parametrizing a disc, hence $(v\cos u,v\sin u)$ is the right choice for the first two coordinates of the patch. And, if we project the patch onto the $z$-axis, we are ignoring what part of the propellor we're looking at and just seeing the plane's progress along the $z$ axis, hence $\lambda u$ should be the patch's $z$-coordinate, where $\lambda$ is the plane's speed.

Comment: Why do we get a disc if we project the patch onto the $xy$-plane?

Comment: You forget about the plane's position on the $z$-axis, so all you see is the propellor spinning, mapping out a disc.

Comment: I got it!! I am still a little confused why $\lambda u$ is the patch's $z$-coordinate... Could you explain it further to me?

Comment: I chose $u$ to be time, so since the plane is flying along the $z$-axis at constant speed $\lambda,$ its $z$-coordinate is $\lambda u$ at time $u$.

Comment: Draw a picture!

Comment: I understood it now!! Thanks for your help!! :-) $$$$ I added also an other question at my initial post... Could you take a look at it? Do you have an idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34078/discussion-between-mary-star-and-francis-begbie).